# Website Section Crashing on iOS Mobile Devices - How Can I Identify and Fix the Issue?

Tags: html, ios, debugging

I am currently facing an issue with a specific section of a website I'm working on: https://www.dashclicks.com/fulfillment/tiktok-ads#setup.

According to some users and testing, this section seems to crash when accessed via an iOS mobile device. I've been unable to replicate the issue on my end, making it difficult for me to pinpoint the exact problem.

According to their report, the website crashes consistently when accessed via iPhone 13 and iPhone 13 Pro devices. However, this problem does not appear on other iPhone models or any other device or platform that we have tested.

To attempt to fix the issue, I've already made a few modifications, such as:

1. Changing the gradients on the page to images.
2. Attempting to add separate properties for gradients.

Unfortunately, these changes haven't solved the problem.

I'm seeking expert guidance to help me:

Replicate this issue: If anyone with an iOS device could try to access the link and share their experience, it would be very useful.

Identify possible causes: I'm not sure what could be causing this section to crash on iOS devices. Are there specific coding practices or elements that are known to cause such issues?

Implement solutions: Based on the possible causes, what actions should I take to prevent the website section from crashing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider including the applicable HTML, script or code with your question.